# Get AD Group Names from List and Group Members Properties with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to `Get-Content` from a text file which includes AD group names.  Then from this group list get the AD user properties for each member `samaccountname`, `name`, `enabled` properties of the user.  The output I'd like to see would look something like this for each group in the text file.

```
Group Name
samaccountname  name  enabled
```

I managed to get the correct output but cannot get it output properly as the `Write-Host` result cannot be output to a file.  Here is the script that gets what I want (well sort of - the first group name appears above the header).

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"  
Get-Content D:\ADGroups.txt | Where{$_ -ne $null -and $_.trim() -ne ""} |   
    foreach{  
        $Group = $_   
        Write-Host "$Group"  
        Get-ADGroup -Identity $Group -Properties members |  
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty members |  
            Get-ADUser -Properties samaccountname, enabled |  
            Select samaccountname, name, Enabled  
    }
```

I've searched and found similar scripts but none of them produced the results I'm looking for.

Comment: Sorry this is my first post.  I don't know why the PowerShell script I posted is not aligned properly.

Comment: Edited, should be fixed in a bit

Comment: Please post the contents of the text file, so that we have enough information to answer your question?

Comment: The contents of the text file (AD groups) would be like this.
AD Group1  
AD Group2  
AD Group3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply be able to do (*with optimizations*):

```
# Apply Silent Errors to only the functions you trust
$SC = ${ErrorAction="SilentlyContinue"}
cat "D:\ADGroups.txt" @SC | ? {"$_".trim()} | % {
    $Group = $_ 
    "$Group"
    Get-ADGroup -Identity $Group -Properties members @SC |
        Select -ExpandProperty members |
        Get-ADUser -Properties samaccountname, enabled @SC |
        Select samaccountname,name,enabled
} | Out-File "D:\Final-Output.txt"
```

This is because `Write-Host` writes directly to the shell and is ignored by PowerShell's stdout stream handling.

Comment: Thank you.  This provided the results I was looking for,